# Node.js: parsing JSON object from an Elasticsearch query

Tags: json, node.js, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch database that I access through a node.js client. I can parse the JSON from elasticsearch to print out the hitsArray which looks like below:

```
[ { _index: 'parties',
    _type: 'suppliers',
    _id: 'AV0uELknL82XeGsCOZ-i',
    _score: 1,
    _source: { name: 'Jabil', address: [Object], rating: 4.2 } },
  { _index: 'parties',
    _type: 'suppliers',
    _id: 'AV0t_yC3L82XeGsCOZ-f',
    _score: 1,
    _source: { name: 'Apple', address: [Object], rating: 4.9 } },
  { _index: 'parties',
    _type: 'suppliers',
    _id: 'AV0t_glkL82XeGsCOZ-d',
    _score: 1,
    _source: { name: 'Flextronics', address: [Object], rating: 4.5 } },
  { _index: 'parties',
    _type: 'suppliers',
    _id: 'AV0t_ox7L82XeGsCOZ-e',
    _score: 1,
    _source: { name: 'FlashMob', address: [Object], rating: 3.5 } } ]
```

Now, I want to parse the `_source` field and print out the `name` field

```
client.search(searchParams).then(function (resp) {
    return Promise.all(resp.hits.hits)
  }).then(function(hitsArray){
    hitsArray.forEach(function(value){
      JSONObject first = hitsArray.getJSONObject(value);
      JSONObject source = first.getJSONObject("_source");
      String name = source.getString("name");
      console.log(name);
    });
  });
```

But I am getting error

```
JSONObject first = hitsArray.getJSONObject(value);
               ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

What am I missing? any suggestion?

Comment: You can use underscore.js for this purpose . it is already implemented in there. May be it can be of some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has no explicit type definitions like that. It looks like those 3 lines may be Java code and not JavaScript code.

As far as getting the actual JavaScript value goes, it appears to already be an object. Just access it with `value._source` (and `value._source.name`).